# AsyncTask onPostExecute not Outputting

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am not reaching an `onPostExecute` in an `AsyncTask` Class.

I call the task this way, inside an `onClick` in a dialog box:

```
new HelpfulTask().execute(passing);
```

Note:  When I hover over the above code, I get a warning:

> A generic Array of ArrayList is created for a varargs
>   parameter.

I am not sure what that means and if that is preventing my Task from even running?

Here is the Task Code:

```
protected class UnHelpfulTask extends
            AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        ArrayList<String> passed;

        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... passing) {
            passed = passing[0];

            String url_select = "http://www.---.com/---/bad.php";

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item", passed.get(0)));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", passed.get(1)));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", passed.get(2)));

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                // read content
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {


            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have voted this down!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

I get no errors on run and in the `onPostExecute`, the Toast never shows.  *(Note:  This is an inner class inside of an `ArrayAdapter.`)*  I also added a toast to see if my `ArrayList` was unwrapping properly and put that in the `onPostExecute` but it never showed either.

How can I test to see if this Task is even running?

Comment: do You mean `UnHelpfulTask` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
```

so it is

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> arr)
```

**Or** change your AsyncTask declaration so it

```
extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, Void>
```

Which is the better idea since you return `null` in `doInBackground()`. The reason why you weren't getting the toast is because you were making a different method than what your AsyncTask specifies. This is why we ususally use the `@Override` annotation - it forces a check for actual overrides, which you need to do in classes like AsyncTasks.

Comment: I went with the second option and it worked.  This is the first time I am actually *passing* arg's into an `AsyncTask` and I did not know how to set that up.  Thanks!